# "witchery of the senses" - What is the meaning of this phrase?

Tags: word-usage

"Thus we are led to infer that the contradiction is an appearance only, and witchery of the senses"- http://www.dictionary.com/browse/witchery

I would be grateful if you could let me know the meaning of the quoted sentence, though I am particularly probing the exact meaning of "witchery of senses".

Comment: 'It is a paradox rather than a real contradiction, but this is hard to discern.'

Comment: I think this requires more context, but as far as I know, the idea of senses being bewitched immediately makes me think of illusions.

Comment: You are quoting a translation of Plato's Republic, Book IX, possibly the [Jowett translation, third edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=dgsnoFCBs7UC). The Republic is a Greek text, not English. It's not clear whether your doubt is about what Plato meant by this passage, or about what the word "witchery" means in English.

Comment: Thank you so much for you cordial response.
@MetaEd, I even did not know what was the exact source of my quoting. I got this sentence from "dictionary.com" at the time when I was finding the meaning of witchery and I understood the word but did not understand the literal meaning of "witchery of senses". However, I've checked the reference you provided.

Comment: That's very helpful. Can you [edit] the question itself to clarify exactly what you are looking for. That will help people give useful answers, and also help other people find the answers when they have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

A witch is a female sorcerer. One who engages in magic and casts spells to influence things around her. The male version is a warlock.

In the sentence I think witchery is used to describe the impact on the senses by an unknown source that results in the appearance. You could substitute "trickery" or "deception" to get the same result.